# Pass variable-length-arguments to variable-length-arguments with different sizes

Tags: java, methods, arguments, variable-length

Suppose I have a method like below:

```
public void setTask(String... args) {
    //...
}
```

How can I create a special version of the above method that has a fixed value for the first member of `args` like below?

<sup>(`args[0]` always has a fixed value *and* `constructorArgs.length == args.length-1`.)</sup>

```
public void setSpecialTask(String... constructorArgs) {
    setTask("SpecialTask", constructorArgs); // ERROR: 'setTask(java.lang.String...)' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'
}
```

> 'setTask(java.lang.String...)' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'

Comment: Is the block quote your error message? If yes, then you are applying a wrong parameter type by putting an array of `String` (`String[]`) rather than an arbitrary amount of `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either declare a new `setTask(String, String...)` method or you can create an array containing the additional string:

```
public void setSpecialTask(String... constructorArgs) {
  String[] args = new String[constructorArgs.length + 1);
  args[0] = "SpecialTask";
  System.arraycopy(constructorArgs, 0, args, 1, constructorArgs.length);

  setTask(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array has a fixed structure. It means that you cannot expand (or reduce) its size once instantiated.
So to achieve your requirement you have to create a new array with the wished capacity.

As alternative while not the most efficient way (with small list it is fine), convert the array to `List`, add the missing element in and convert back it to an array :

```
public void setSpecialTask(String... constructorArgs) {
    String[] array = Arrays.asList("SpecialTask", constructorArgs)
                           .toArray(new String[constructorArgs.length+1]);
    setTask(array);    
}
```

Or both simple and efficient (doesn't require any intermediary `List`) in Java 8 :

```
String[] array = Stream.of("SpecialTask", constructorArgs)
                       .toArray(String[]::new);
setTask("SpecialTask", array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.